# How do I signal other Cocoa apps that preferences were changed?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I'm changing the **.GlobalPreferences NSUserSubstitutions** preference through the `NSUserDefaults` class (through PyObjC, but that's besides the point).

This preference controls the text substitutions feature (e.g. which can substitute "©" for "(c)") of OS X.

After changing the preference, I want it to apply immediately in all running apps. When it's changed through the System Preferences, it applies immediately. How should I signal other apps to apply it immediately?

**Update:** Here's the project: https://github.com/ikonst/mac-tex-substitutions

Comment: There may not be a way to. `NSUserDefaults` [uses a per-app cache](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-97569) that is updated periodically. Your app can request immediate synchronization for itself, but unless the other apps have registered to act on `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`, they will probably just wait for the automatic sync. I may have missed something, however.

Comment: I would've thought so, if System Preferences didn't manage to apply immediately, but it does manage... so there must be a way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gotIt:) name:nil object:nil];
```

I was able to detect that the System Preferences application posts a notification named `NSUserReplacementItemsEnabledChanged` when the text substitutions preferences change.

Knowing that, you can now post the adequate notification after changing the preferences to let know all open applications:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NSUserReplacementItemsEnabledChanged" object:self];
```

Keep in mind that `NSUserReplacementItemsEnabledChanged` is not documented anywhere, so this behavior can change any time.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, this is the notification for enabling and disabling the feature. The notification for changing the list is "NSSpellServerReplacementsChanged".

Comment: Hey Guillaume! I have changed network proxy setting and used the code above to listen for notifications that were triggered and found none. Do you know what could be the reason. I have a question open here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210701/notification-that-tells-the-system-that-preferences-plist-has-changed